# Proper ideals are invertible

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

I am reading through Cox's book *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* and I am stuck with some proofs in Chapter 7 (I have the 2nd edition). There, the author presents the following Lemma:

> **Lemma 7.5:** Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\tau)$ be a quadratic field, and let $ax^2+bx+c$ be the minimal polynomial of $\tau$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are relatively prime integers. Then $[1,\tau]$ is a proper fractional ideal for the order $[1,a\tau]$ of $K$.

Shortly after, he proceeds to prove that proper fractional ideals for an order of a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ are invertible.

> First note that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$ (see Exercise 7.8), so that $\mathfrak{a}=[\alpha, \beta]$ for some $\alpha, \beta\in K$. Then $\mathfrak{a}=\alpha [1, \tau]$, where $\tau=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$. If $ax^2+bx+c$, $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\tau$, then Lemma 7.5 implies that $\mathcal{O}=[1, a\tau]$.

I don't get how the above follows from Lemma 7.5. The same reasoning is used later in the proof of Lemma 7.14:

> If we write $\mathfrak{a}$ in the form $\mathfrak{a}=a[1,\tau]$, then Lemma 7.5 implies that $\mathcal{O}=[1, a\tau]$.

Any help in understanding how the author devises these conclusions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The order $A = \{x \in K \,\vert \, x \mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathfrak{a}\}$ is, by definition, independent of any order $\mathcal{O}$ for which $\mathfrak{a}$ is a fractional $\mathcal{O}$-ideal. As $\mathfrak{a}$ is a proper fractional ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ by assumption, we have, by the definition of *proper*, $A = \mathcal{O}$. It is also a proper fractional ideal of $[1, a \tau]$ by Lemma 7.5, thus $A = [1, a\tau]$. The conclusion follows from the transitivity of equality.